# Getting \u200b in filename when using OS to scan directory for files

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

I'm trying to scan a directory for files using this code:

```
result = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(PATH) for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.json']
```

Most of them are coming back correct but a few of them are coming back with \u200b in them. When I put it in a with open() statement, I get an error message saying:

```
IOError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

What's even stranger is that when I manually look at the file name in the directory it's stored in, there's no \u200b to be found. But if I manually try to read in the name I see printed in the directory, it says "file not found".

How do I solve this issue? The ideal solution I need is a way to read these files in with open() statements without having to manually go and rename all these files without special characters.

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend moving to `pathlib` and use `glob()`

Comment: [This](https://dfarq.homeip.net/u200b-what-it-is-and-why-it-messes-up-your-code-or-data/) might help clarify the `\u200b` character and why you can’t see it.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a true solution to reading in files from a directory that have \u200b character in them without manually changing the file name? Does the problem stem from the person who saved the file?